# Understanding CustTable in multiple layers from a .Net developer perspective

Tags: axapta

`CustTable` exists in SYS, USR, & USP layers.

I am just wondering if it is right to think that CustTable in each layer is just a partial class.

From a .net developer perspective i am wondering if there is a better way to understand this?

Comment: If you find an answer useful then please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, sort of, but it is a dangerous analogy. It may match in some places and not in other.

And from a .Net developer perspective layers are not visible and the table is the combined table as seen if you do not show layers in the AOT.

To fully understand go for [the official explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa851164%28v=ax.50%29.aspx).